Spring Boot 3: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
I recently upgraded my Kotlin-based Spring Boot application from version 2.x to version 3.3.4, and it is now running successfully.
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-10-19T12:29:11.046+09:00 ERROR 35432 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [me.servito.businessservice.BusinessServiceApplication]: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:544) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:746) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:743) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:714) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:417) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:789) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:607) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225) ~[spring-test-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152) ~[spring-test-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:122) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:106) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:63) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260) ~[spring-test-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163) ~[spring-test-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:383) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.3.jar:5.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:63) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.3.jar:1.10.3]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:220) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:382) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:273) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:246) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:534) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:512) ~[testcontainers-1.19.8.jar:1.19.8]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerState.getMappedPort(ContainerState.java:161) ~[testcontainers-1.19.8.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(PostgreSQLContainer.java:92) ~[postgresql-1.17.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SupplierUtils.resolve(SupplierUtils.java:52) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicValuesPropertySource.getProperty(DynamicValuesPropertySource.java:44) ~[spring-test-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:125) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.findPropertyValue(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:99) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:75) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:61) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:552) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.hasDataSourceUrlProperty(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.getMatchOutcome(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:140) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    ... 103 common frames omitted

Here is my Kotlin Test case:
package me.xxxxx.businessservice.controller

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import java.math.BigDecimal

@Testcontainers
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class ControllerTests : BaseIntegrationTest() {

    @MockBean
    protected lateinit var privilegeService: PrivilegeService


    companion object {

        @Container
        val container = PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>("postgres:14").apply {
            withDatabaseName("servito")
            withUsername("admin")
            withPassword("test")
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun properties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.datasource.url", container::getJdbcUrl)
            registry.add("spring.datasource.password", container::getPassword)
            registry.add("spring.datasource.username", container::getUsername)
        }

    }

    @Test
    fun createOrder() {
        //testcode
    }

}


@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class BaseIntegrationTest(){

}

The error implies that the Testcontainer may not have fully started before Spring tries to access the JdbcUrl. Could this be caused by the Spring application context starting prematurely, or could there be an issue with the timing of @DynamicPropertySource in Spring Boot 3.x?
Has the setup for Testcontainers changed with Spring Boot 3.x?
Could the application context be starting too early, before Testcontainers is fully initialized?

(1) Try to temporarily rename init.sql to _init.sql, and rename data.sql to _data.sql (2) Create the file application-test.properties in test/resources, file , do not include spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username, spring.datasource.password

@life888888 I do not have a data.sql and also no init.sql. In my test => application.yaml there is no sprint.datasource => url, username and password

As you can read in this spring-boot article and also in test containers documentation, there have been some updates in annotations used in spring boot3 with test containers.
You have to replace this block of code
companion object {

    @Container
    val container = PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>("postgres:14").apply {
        withDatabaseName("servito")
        withUsername("admin")
        withPassword("test")
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @DynamicPropertySource
    fun properties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", container::getJdbcUrl)
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", container::getPassword)
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", container::getUsername)
    }

}

with
companion object {

    @Container
    @JvmStatic
    @ServiceConnection
    val container = PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>("postgres:14").apply {
        withDatabaseName("servito")
        withUsername("admin")
        withPassword("test")
    }

}

